# Why forecast accuracy is very high in Restricted VAR but not in individual OLS estimate?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, estimation, least-squares, vector-autoregression

When a **VAR** is estimated and tested on the test data the RMSE of the model was around 25. However when I estimated a **restricted VAR** by setting coefficients of the lagged terms of the dependent variable to 0, the RMSE reduced to 10.

I also estimated the same equation by imposing **restrictions as above using OLS**. But the coefficients obtained were different from what I obtained through the restricted VAR model and the RMSE was higher than what I obtained through the restricted VAR.

***Why forecast accuracy is very high in Restricted VAR but not in individual OLS estimate?***

Comment: *setting coefficients of the lagged terms of the dependent variable*: in a VAR, every variable is a dependent variable, and every regressor is a lag of one of the dependent variables. What variables were left on the right hand side after your restrictions?

Comment: I have 5 variables in my VAR. Though I fit a VAR my main focus is on predicting and interpreting one variable (suppose gdp). I set the effect of gdp(-1), gdp(-2) and gdp(-3) on gdp to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same model but different estimates, then obviously the estimation method must be different. I presume your restricted VAR model was estimated using generalized least squares (GLS) which under some assumptions is known to be the efficient estimator. Equation-by-equation ordinary least squares (EbE OLS) is efficient for an unrestricted VAR but not for a restricted one.

The difference in forecast accuracy must also be a result of the different estimators. Whether GLS beat OLS by chance or it is a genuinely better estimator in your case is an open question. A Diebold-Mariano test could offer some insight into that.

Comment: Yes, the restricted VAR was estimated using GLS. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: @RichardHardly I didn't know about that option. The answer was very clear and precise! Really appreciate it.